# How to JOIN tables using RIGHT JOIN in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query with the following SQL:

```
SELECT tours_atp.NAME_T
      ,today_atp.TOUR
      ,today_atp.ID1
      ,today_atp.ID2
      ,qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.LastOfnElo_Ov AS ID1_nElo_ov
FROM (today_atp INNER JOIN tours_atp ON today_atp.TOUR = tours_atp.ID_T)
INNER JOIN qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp ON today_atp.ID1 = qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.ID
WHERE ((tours_atp.RANK_T Between 1 And 4) AND today_atp.RESULT="")
ORDER BY tours_atp.NAME_T;
```

It works fine.

I now want to build in another table into the query using a `RIGHT JOIN` as follows:

`RIGHT JOIN qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp ON qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp.ID = today_atp.ID1`

I've tried adding it onto the end of `FROM` as follows:

```
SELECT tours_atp.NAME_T, today_atp.TOUR, today_atp.ID1, today_atp.ID2, qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.LastOfnElo_Ov AS ID1_nElo_ov
FROM ((today_atp INNER JOIN tours_atp ON today_atp.TOUR = tours_atp.ID_T) INNER JOIN qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp ON today_atp.ID1 = qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.ID) RIGHT JOIN qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp ON qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp.ID = today_atp.ID1
WHERE (((tours_atp.RANK_T) Between 1 And 4) AND ((today_atp.RESULT)=""))
ORDER BY tours_atp.NAME_T;
```

However I'm getting a "JOIN expression not supported" error - why would this be? What does the correct syntax look like?

Comment: Missing ()'s around last join perhaps....  I always disliked access joins becuase of the ()'s

Comment: Tried various combinations of ()s around that section of SQL to no avail...

Comment: still getting an error or not getting desired results.  The where clause negates the right join since it would eliminate null records. need to move the limiting critiera to the join as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pasting this into the SQL editor and let MSAccess add the ()'s it wants:

```
SELECT tours_atp.NAME_T
     , today_atp.TOUR
     , today_atp.ID1
     , today_atp.ID2
     , qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.LastOfnElo_Ov AS ID1_nElo_ov
FROM today_atp 
INNER JOIN tours_atp 
   ON today_atp.TOUR = tours_atp.ID_T
  and tours_atp.RANK_T Between 1 And 4
  and today_atp.RESULT=""
INNER JOIN qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp 
   ON today_atp.ID1 = qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.ID
RIGHT JOIN qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp 
   ON qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp.ID = today_atp.ID1
ORDER BY tours_atp.NAME_T
```

or re-arrange to use a left...

```
SELECT tours_atp.NAME_T
     , today_atp.TOUR
     , today_atp.ID1
     , today_atp.ID2
     , qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.LastOfnElo_Ov AS ID1_nElo_ov
FROM qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp 
LEFT JOIN today_atp 
   ON qry_today_Elo_sur1_prep_atp.ID = today_atp.ID1
INNER JOIN tours_atp 
   ON today_atp.TOUR = tours_atp.ID_T
  and tours_atp.RANK_T Between 1 And 4
  and today_atp.RESULT=""
INNER JOIN qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp 
   ON today_atp.ID1 = qry_today_Elo_ov_prep_atp.ID 
ORDER BY tours_atp.NAME_T
```

Comment: Thanks - will try this out tomorrow. As a quick aside question - how do you get Access to retain the formatting of SQL? As soon as I save, close and reopen then all tabs and new lines disappear - makes it incredibly hard to follow!!

Comment: You can't to my knowledge.  It's just how Access does things.